# Is JIRA Web Data Connector live or is it just an extract?

Tags: jira, tableau-api, jira-plugin

I am trying to create dashboards in Tableau from my JIRA data and I was investigating on ways with which I could pull data into Tableau. I found this online:

https://marketplace.atlassian.com/plugins/com.kaanha.jira.tableau/cloud/overview

I wanted to know if the WDC created would have a live connection with JIRA or is it just a one-time extract from JIRA?

Thank you!

Comment: i recommend flagging this as off-topic. There is no development related issue here.

Answer (score 2):

With WDCs it is not possible to have a live connection.
You can refresh the data manually for Tableau Desktop or if you have access to Tableau Server you will have to install the WDC on Tableau server and let it refresh on a schedule to make the latest data available to users.